# How to remove sequences of "000" from right of a string in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to remove sequences of 3 zeros from the right of a string.

I used str.rstrip('000') but it doesn't work. It just removes all the zeros to the right no matter the amount.

For example 1010101010100000 should become 1010101010100

Comment: If the input is 1010101010100010 what should the output be?

Comment: And what if the input is 1010101010100000000? (with 6 consecutive trailing zeroes)

Comment: @Stuart It should be the same (1010101010100010) since there are no sequences of 000 at the right of the string. However ErikMD's solution works perfectly well!

Comment: @Aleya I think it would be worthwhile for you to learn a bit about regexes in order to understand the differences between the answers provided. For example, ErikMD's regex matches 3, 6, 9, 12, etc. trailing zeroes while mine matches only exactly 3 zeroes. The appropriate choice depends on your use case and needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just rely on [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), and write e.g.:

```py
import re

s = '1010101010100000000'

res = re.sub(r'(000)*$', '', s)
# remove trailing zeroes if there are 3⋅n of these
# (you should just remove the '*' if you want n=1)

print(res)
# → 1010101010100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex. For example:

```
import re

a = "1010101010100000"

a = re.sub('000$', '', a)

print(a)
```

Comment: @Stuart "I am trying to remove sequences of 3 zeros" Not quite sure why you're  assuming from the post that OP wants to remove *at most* 3 zeros...

Comment: @Stuart: not really, the OP's comment dealt with 1's, not about several sequences of 000.

Comment: @Stuart OP's comment to ThePeeps191's answer is referring to a situation in which removing the last 3 chars would also remove a 1 digit. OP should clarify whether they want to remove *exactly* 3 trailing zeros, or either one, two, or three trailing zeros.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works as well! I'm sorry for not clarifying whether it's many or just 1 sequence.

Comment: @Aleya No problem :) As I said in my comment on your question, regexes are a powerful tool and mastering it would give you the power to craft exactly the ones you need, so I highly recommend learning a bit about them.

Answer (score 1):

To alter the string from right to left, we can simply reverse the string, replace all occurrences of "000" and reverse it back to it's original state.

```py
s = s[::-1].replace("000", "")[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `str[:-3]` to remove the last the three digits no matter what (using a slice).

Comment: That would give an unwanted value for string 1010101010100010 for example. I cannot remove any "1" from the binary number.